# sshfs can't access symbolic links without password

Tags: linux, passwords, debian, symlink, sshfs

I was trying to make a directory in my computer's home (under Debian Jessie) of my distant session at school.
I don't want to use any password, I would like to do "cd work" and see my distant session.

So I checked the manual of **sshfs** which mounts an ssh session in a directory.
Then I figured out that the symbolic links were not followed.
So I used the option "**-o follow_symlinks**" and it worked fine.

In order to connect at work without password, I created an ssh key public and private (with **ssh-keygen**), then I sent it to the server (with **ssh-copy-id**). When I try to connect with ssh, the server isn't asking for password.
But when I try to use this key with the sshfs, the server isn't asking for password but all the **symbolic links are broken** !!

```
[16-05-17 19:47]ShellCode-Pc:/tmp/test shellcode) ls
ls: cannot access Music: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access VMs: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access Documents: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access Desktop-Windows: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access Videos: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access Bibliotheque: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access Rushes: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access Downloads: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access Pictures: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access ISOs: No such file or directory
Bibliotheque  boost_1_60_0  boost_1_60_0.tar.gz  Desktop-Windows  Documents  Downloads  ISOs  Music  Pictures  Remise  Rushes  Videos  VMs  Wallpapers  Www 
[16-05-17 19:48]ShellCode-Pc:/tmp/test shellcode)
```

The home's folders like *boost_1_60_0* here are ok, but not the symbolic links... I just don't understand why. Does anybody have an answer for that ? :)

Answer (score 0):

You might probably want to use `-o transform_symlinks` rather than `-o follow_symlinks`.

Comment: I already tried and it doesn't work ! `[16-05-17 22:19]ShellCode-Pc:/tmp/lol shellcode) file Documents
Documents: broken symbolic link to /mnt/iut/user/Documents
[16-05-17 22:19]ShellCode-Pc:/tmp/lol shellcode) 
`